# How do I create a framework in protractor using Jasmine for testing Applications?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor, webstorm

I am new to Protractor. Can I know how to create a framework in protractor.

I have gone through some videos of how to create a framework.They have specified that we can use POM. But is there any other way of how to create a framework. Could you share me some insights about this.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking, what do you mean when you say you want to create a framework in protractor?

Comment: Hi @MartinBlaustein, i just wanted to ask can i create a framework as we do in selenium webdriver. Like Hybrid framework or data driven framework.

Comment: @rajesh.h.sraj Protractor is basically javascript version of selenium webdriver with added functionality for testing angular applications. Anything you do with java, python, c#, selenium you can build here.

Answer (score 0):

[Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) is one of the javascript bindings for [Selenium Webdriver](http://www.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/), which has many feature, but is probably best known for working well with [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) apps (though not a necessity for its use).

I have an [example project on GitHub](https://github.com/qualityshepherd/protractor-example) that might give you a nice head-start with Protractor.

FYI, a POM file is part of Maven (Java), and not used in Protractor.

Comment: Thank you for the example project. As you said POM is part of Maven and not used in Protractor. But as i see in the project i can see that you have used Page object in the GitHub project.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the same.

Also can you please tell me what type of frameworks can be used in Protractor. (Data driven, Method driven or Hybrid as in Selenium).

Comment: Sure. You can use or create data-driven, or keyword frameworks with Protractor. I'm sure they exist, though I don't use them. Also, POM and the page object model are different things... similar only in acronyms :)